# Set up Slidemenu - example not working

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to use the SlideMenu library with ActionBarSherlock. 
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

I had not issue installing actionbarsherlock and run the examples provided.
But, can't do the same with the example og the SlideMenu library :(

I can set up the library fine (or so i think) without errors (under eclipse with jre6).

For the slidemenu example, i created the project, and added com_actionbarssherlock.jar as a "referenced libraies".

But i have lots of : 
 - R cannot resolve erros ;
 - can't overrides some methods erros;
- methods from actionbarsherlock are not recognized ; ex : "The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type BaseActivity"
 - can't load style from actionbarsherlock erros.

It is as if the project doesn't see the classes from actionbarsherlock.

Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: try cleaning your project and run again

Comment: Check this page , 100% working ;) [Installing SlidingMenu Android library and example](http://boroniatechnologies.com/installing-slidingmenu-android-library-and-example/)

Comment: You gotta stop it.When have problems,there is not enough documentation.Oh actually no documentation.so skip this sliding menu.

Answer (score 135):

For the error

> "The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type BaseActivity"

Inside the SlidingMenu library, edit the class SlidingFragmentActivity to extend SherlockFragmentActivity (like below). Then clean and rebuild, this method should now be found.

```
public class SlidingFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements SlidingActivityBase {
```

[Source](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/145)

Comment: Thank you very much !!!   after long frustrating search finally i can run example !!

now next i have to look for "how to implement it in my own project"

please help me if you can ! Thanks again. +1 for you

Comment: I wonder how they can run that sample app without error to push that to Github master branch ??

Comment: don't forget clean the project.

Comment: Its work... great after spending 2hrs.
We need to add Sherlock library for both sliding menu library as well as actual application.
Tanks buddyy...

Comment: Many thanks for this. I did the above and then added ActionBarSherlock as a library to the SlidingMenu library project. Surely there must be a reason why this builds okay on the developers' system - I'd be very keen to understand why.

Comment: I did this and Im getting a nullpointerexception at getSlidingMenu() (which is implemented in my class and it returns null) so what do I do?

Comment: The examples from SlidingMenu needs ABS. Why is this not done per default in git?

Answer (score 0):

Look add Problems tab to see there are any error ?
Right click your project and check your all Libraries.
If everthing ok, try to clean your project.

Comment: Ok, i did check my libraries. I did import the jar files of the both libraries. I switch to put them in the "add library" in the android tab of the build path menu.

I still have two errors : - getSupportActionBar() method is undefined. This method is supposed to be in actionbarsherlock. I don't understand why eclipse doesn't see it. - onOptionsItemSelected() can't be override. Same thing, eclipse doesn't see that it is part of actionbarsherlock. My example activity extends slidemneuactivty wich extends sherlockactivity, so it should work.

I did try to clean my project.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

There are [lots of issues](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/search?q=SherlockFragmentActivity&ref=cmdform&type=Issues) on github with that bug. Mrcb123's solution works, but [I suppose](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/200#issuecomment-38787580) it will be good to separate example ABS dependency from library.