# HoloEveryWhere + ActionBarSherlock + SlidingMenu Error

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I downloaded latest HoloEveryWhere

Then  `Import from existing code --> library folder --> Properties --> isLibrary --> Ok`

Then  `Import from existing code --> Demo folder --> Properties --> addLibrary --> Library`

And in demo i have i errors, see in images

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the imports in the second image and then clean and rebuild.

```
import org.holoeverywhere.slidingmenu.R;
import org.holoeverywhere.slidingmenu.example; 
import org.holoeverywehre.slidingmenu.SlidingMenu;
```

Also ensure that Inside the SlidingMenu library, that the class SlidingFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity. Check the link below for more information on this. This is the only problem I could think of for the  getSupportActionBar() without seeing the actual errors.

[Editing SlidingMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438657/set-up-slidemenu-example-not-working/13537257#13537257)

EDIT:

It may also be worth checking that your project is referencing the correct libraries. Right click on your example project in the package explorer -> Properties, then select android and check that in the library section that there are references to the SlidingMenu and ActionBarSherlock libraries.