# How to Building slidingmenu sample android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-sliding

I'm very much enthusiastic to use the sliding menu activity for android. i downloaded the third party lib [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), actually i'm facing lots of problem while building.

i'm able to build Action bar, also i'm able to build the slidingmenu activity LIB, but i'm unable to build the example activity.

Can any one please download this once and build & tell its working great for you or not. If so please post the changes required, as it will be helpful for so many people.

Comment: why dont you just download the demo in the play store....

Comment: If not explain what errors you are receiving.

Comment: @tyczj, i downloaded that demo app from playstore, works well. i need to build myself so i'm asking

Comment: @Mrcb123, the errors are related to ABS, but i included it still its giving me the same problem. could you plzzzz download once and try in ur machine, it would be a big help from your end

Comment: are the errors along the lines of "The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type BaseActivity" or is there a dependency issue?

Comment: Yup, u are right, its "The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type BaseActivity". pls tell me the way to solve them... it will be great if you post ans.. because for new people who download that lib and try to run the sample they face issues. So pls post the step by step resolution for it. Thanks

Comment: I won't re-type it, but here is a link to a similar post, please check and see if that answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/13537257/970843 . If you have any more questions let me know.

Comment: You are perfectly right, yes i am able to build it now. thanks for the ans, however ill retype the ans below.. thanks again